# WPF gridview field bound to textbox and combobox based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, binding, combobox

I have a wpf combobox in gridview which has dataview as binding source. The combobox populates the values but selected item is always null on load of combobox.

Objects that combobox is binded to:

```
public class ChargeCodeValidValues
{
    #region Properties

    public DataTable ChargeCodesValidValuesTable { get; set; }
    public DataView dvChargeCodeValidValues { get; set; }
     #region Properties

    //public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int Code { get; set; }
    //public string Description { get; set; }



    #endregion

   // public ChargeCodeValidValue() { }

    //public ChargeCodeValidValue(DataRow dr)
    //{
    //    Id = dr.Field<int>("Id");
    //    Code = dr.Field<int>("Code");
    //    Description = dr.Field<string>("Description");

    //}

    #endregion
    #region Constructor

    public ChargeCodeValidValues()
    {
        LoadChargeCodesValidValues();
    }

    public void LoadChargeCodesValidValues()
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        DataTable dataTable = db.ExecuteQuery("upGet_ChargeCodesValidValues", "ChargeCodesValidValues", "ID");

        this.ChargeCodesValidValuesTable = dataTable;
        this.dvChargeCodeValidValues = ChargeCodesValidValuesTable.DefaultView;


    }




    //public static void GetChargeCodeValidValues()
    //{
    //    Database db = new Database();
    //    DataTable dataTable = db.ExecuteQuery("upGet_ChargeCodesValidValues", "ChargeCodesValidValues", "ID");           
    //}

    #endregion
}

public class ChargeCodeValidValue
{
    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }



    #endregion

    public ChargeCodeValidValue() { }

    public ChargeCodeValidValue(DataRow dr)
    {
        Id = dr.Field<int>("Id");
        Code = dr.Field<int>("Code");
        Description = dr.Field<string>("Description");

    }

    public  void LoadChargeCodeValidValue(DataRow dr)
    {
        Id = dr.Field<int>("Id");
        Code = dr.Field<int>("Code");
        Description = dr.Field<string>("Description");

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="combodescriptionTemplate">
                                <ComboBox
                                     Name="cboCombo"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding dvChargeCodeValidValues}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                     SelectedItem="Description"
                                     >                                    
                                    <ComboBox.DataContext>
                                        <Objects:ChargeCodeValidValues/>
                                    </ComboBox.DataContext>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <local:TotalCellTemplateSelector x:Key="totalcellTemplateSelector"                                                             
                                combodescriptionTemplate="{StaticResource combodescriptionTemplate}"/>
```

gridview column :

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" FieldName="Description" Width="Auto" MinWidth="132" AllowMoving="False" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource totalcellTemplateSelector}" /> -->
```

this column is textbox by default. It changes to combobox based on values from other column

Combobox selected item is always null. I know it is a binding issue but i am not able to figure it out and i am new to wpf.

Can someone please help

Comment: Can you put example?

Comment: This is not really helping, please post some more code or give a more insightful explaination

Comment: I have edited my question with my code

Comment: Can someone please help me?